# URI() is not the usual Ruby receiver.message format, what is it?

Tags: ruby, uri

The [Ruby core URI module](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html) is called in a strange way:

```
URI("http://example.com")
```

It is not the usual `receiver.message` format, so what does Ruby call and do here? Is it a shortcut for `URI.new()` or is it `Kernel.URI()`, or something completely different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is Kernel::URI

http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/lib/uri/common.rb#1228

I suspect you were trying to stub it. I was trying to do so myself, but I have not managed to stub it out with rspec. I ended up using the WebMock gem.

Answer (score 1):

It *is* the normal message sending format. If you don't specify an explicit receiver, Ruby will assume an implicit receiver of `self`.

However, in this particular case, the receiver is actually irrelevant, because the method doesn't do anything interesting (call private methods or access instance variables) with `self`. Such methods, which are called with an implicit receiver of `self` but don't actually do anything with `self` are usually defined as private instance methods of `Kernel`<sup>†</sup>, which, being mixed into `Object` is in the ancestry chain of almost every Ruby object.

So, in this particular case, the method is `Kernel#URI`. Other similar methods include `Kernel#Integer`, `Kernel#Float`, `Kernel#Array`, `Kernel#String`, `Kernel#require`, `Kernel#puts`, `Kernel#load`, `Kernel#p`, `Kernel#gets`, etc.

---

<sup>†</sup> Unless they are only meant to be called within a module body, in which case they are defined in `Module`, e.g. `Module#attr_reader`, `Module#attr_writer`, `Module#attr_accessor`, `Module#define_method`, etc.